# How to make an api get request with a function?

Tags: javascript, api, get, axios

I'm trying to generate a new, random dog image with the breed name underneath using calls to the dog.ceo api using Axios, sent out by the `genNewImage()` function linked to my button, this is my javascript:

```js
function genNewImage(){
axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random') //This is the api I'm calling to.
.then((body) => {
var url = body.data.message;    

var image = document.getElementById("dogImg");
var dogText = document.getElementById("dogText");
  
var urlCutter = url.split('/')[4].split('-'); //Get the breed name from the retrieved url
    
var first = urlCutter[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + urlCutter[1].split("").slice(1,urlCutter[1].length).join(""); //Get the first part of the breed name & capitalize first letter.

var second = urlCutter[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + urlCutter[0].split("").slice(1,urlCutter[0].length).join(""); //Get the second part of the breed name & capitalize first letter.
  
  image.src = url;  // set the src of the image object
    dogText.innerHTML  = "This is a: " + first + " " + second;  //Set the dog breed name in the paragraph
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log('Error', err.statusCode);
})
 };
```

```html
<button onClick="genNewImage()">Click for a random image</button>

<img id="dogImg" src="">

<p><strong><span id ="dogText"> This is a: </span></strong></p>
```

I'm still really new to Axios and api calls in general. My function isn't working even though I've already used this code to make the api call on new page load and I don't understand why this one doesn't work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Did you import <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>; I imported and checked it worked

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan the error message is "Cannot access 'axios' before initialization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the code itself but a semantic problem.

Consider these two example URLs

https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/spaniel-cocker/n02102318_9714.jpg

https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/chow/n02112137_6458.jpg

Go trough your code line by line and you will see that the problem occurs when you try to get the first name of the breed. You access the splitted URL array at index 1. You split the array by '-' delimiter. If the URL (breed) doesnt contain a '-' like the second URL does an error will be thrown because the array at index 1 is undefined. So before using the value at index 1 check if it is set at all. This will make your code run.

The error message also indicates that a variable is undefined.

```js
function genNewImage() {
  axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    .then((body) => {
      let url = body.data.message;
      let image = document.getElementById("dogImg");
      let dogText = document.getElementById("dogText");

      let urlCutter = url.split('/')[4].split('-');
      let first = typeof(urlCutter[1]) == 'undefined' ? "" : urlCutter[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + urlCutter[1].split("").slice(1, urlCutter[1].length).join("");;
      let second = urlCutter[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + urlCutter[0].split("").slice(1, urlCutter[0].length).join("");
      image.src = url; // set the src of the image object
      dogText.innerHTML = "This is a: " + first + " " + second; //Set the dog breed name in the paragraph
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)

    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>


<button onClick="genNewImage()">Click for a random image</button>

<img id="dogImg" src="">

<p><strong><span id ="dogText"> This is a: </span></strong></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for solving the issue of my api call sometimes coming back with weird data and not loading, I was wondering what was causing that. For some reason, even pasting your code in doesn't seem to fix the problem, I'm getting an error message: "Cannot access 'axios' before initialization" I used npm to install it to my root directory and I added it to the javascript file holding the function using require but it's still not working.

Comment: So are you using it in node or the html file? If the second is the case you have to reference to axios using a script like in my snippet.

Comment: I have a central app.js file that uses a copy of this function and app.get to render the page initially, I also have another version of the function in another js file that I'm linking to the html file using the script tag. I can tell they're linked correctly as other functions in the js file work perfectly in my html. The script tag in my html looks like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/funcs.js"></script>`  are you saying I need to somehow reference Axios in the script tag itself? This is my first time trying to build something in node so I'm really not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: The error message I'm getting no matter what I do is "Cannot access 'axios' before initialization"

Comment: Nope I've figured it out, I had 2 consts with the same name, it works perfectly now thanks!